# Problemas con mostrar datos en page con JSX la data no se muestra en la page correcta

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Tengo dos pages en jsx en secciones distintas de un sitio pero cuando cargo data se carga en la primera page que encuentra no necesariamente en la que estoy.

Por ejemplo tengo la page TaskInformation y la muestro en

- account/TaskInformation
- allaccount/Task/TaskInformation

ambas pages las obtengo de un import ya que hacen exactamente lo mismo, pero cuando cargo la data me carga o en la primera page(account/TaskInformation) o en la segunda (allaccount/Task/TaskInformation)

el import lo realizo de la siguiente forma :

import Task_Info from './task_info';

El problema que tengo para aclarar es : La data no se carga en la seccion correcta como puedo hacer para que cada page se carge con la informacion?..

y Como carga JSX la data siempre la pone en la primera page que encuentra?

Comment: Te aconsejo que leas [ask] y completes el [tour]. La pregunta es vaga en detalles y es complicado entender tu escenario. ¿Podrías [edit] para añadir más detalles, como el tipo de datos que no se muestran correctamente y de dónde los obtiene ese componente? Mostrar código siempre ayuda, mira lo que es un [mcve].

Comment: Si mostras el código capaz que te pueda ayudar, porque pueden estar mal los endpoints o la menera de compartir la data.